# типы аккаунтов социальных сетей и месенджеров android

Tags: android, соцсети

Где можно найти данные о том, какой `type` использует приложение для сохранения аккаунта на устройстве?
Google - "com.google";
Twitter - "com.twitter.android.auth.login";

---

В частности интересует конерктно этот список:

- Вконтакте;
- Facebook;
- Viber;
- WhatsApp;
- Telegram;
- Instagram;